# Некорректно работает событие Paste

Tags: jquery

[image]

Если вставить текст первый раз, то событие не проходит, а если второй то всё нормально.

```js
$(document).on("paste", 'input[name=create--post--youtube]', function(e) {
  var url = $('input[name=create--post--youtube]').val();
  console.info(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="create--post--youtube" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что paste срабатывает еще до того, как значение инпута изменено. В зависимости от задачи, если не принципиально - можно использовать `'input'` вместо `'paste'`. Но он будет каждый раз срабатывать и при вводе любых символов.

А с `paste` будет так:

```js
$(document).on("paste", '#create--post', function(e) {
  var url = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  console.info(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="create--post" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="create--post--youtube" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input[name=create--post--youtube]').on("paste", function() { // ;(document).on(... если элемент добавлен динамически
  setTimeout(function () {
    var url = $('input[name=create--post--youtube]').val();
    console.info(url);
  }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="create--post--youtube" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```